# React-Native welcome screen mess with the background image

Tags: react-native

From some reason I'm trying to set a big background and fit it to the mobile screen, I mean the width will be 100% and the height will be dynamic.

Also I have a bigger logo and I want to fit it into the screen so I gave it width & height but it's looks cut.. What i'm doing wrong? Just want a nice "Pre loader" screen with mean a background and logo in the middle..

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Preload extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainBox}>
            <Image source={require('../app_images/preload/bg.jpg')} style={styles.bgImage} />
            <View><Image source={require('../app_images/preload/logo.png')} style={styles.logoImage} /></View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainBox:{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        width: null,
        height: null
    },bgImage: {
        position:'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    },logoImage: {
        width: 100,
        height: 150
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Preload', () => Preload);
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to change Image's `resizeMode` property? `cover`, `contain`

Answer (score 0):

For the logo, you should use `contain` resizeMode.

```
logoImage: {
        width: 100,
        height: 150,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
}
```

For background mode, I think you can use `cover` and keep the `view` above it transparent